# Blazored/LocalStorage working in a service class?

Tags: blazored

Is there an example to Inject the Blazored/LocalStorage in a Singleton Service Class? Or how can I get an instance of the Blazored/LocalStorage within the Service Class as needed? (So not injected but on-demand)

I had an example of the code I wrote, but was asked to reduce the detail in the question so making it a more broad question.

I am new to coding in Blazor, so apologize if I didn't provide the right information, or this is a stupid question and I am guessing there is something simple I am missing.

Any help would be greatly Appreciated.

Comment: try to re edit your question and please remove any unnecessary text from your question, before posting on stackOverflow, try to see how to ask a good question to avoid downVoting

Comment: Ok I simplified the question. Is this better?

Comment: I think you got an answer, try to comment or accept or refuse the answer to help others when come and see your question and the answers on it

Answer (score 0):

Ok. So I had to do a couple of things to make this work, but seems to be working.

1. For some reason I had to close my VS and reopen because all my breakpoints were being captured by the browser instead of VS.
2. I modified the code to have:

- private IlocalStorageService localStorage;
- public AppSettingsService(IlocalstorageService inLocalStorage) 
  { localStorage = inLocalStorage; }

In my progam.cs I have

- builder.Services.AddBlazoredLocalStorage();
- builder.Services.AddScoped<IAppSettingsService, AppSettingsService>();

FYI.. AppSettingsService is a new service I created that each component will Inject so that component can get to the local storage, and will use this AppSettingsService to raise events any time a value changes from another component so all other components can update their state.

As I continue to learn, apologize if I wasted anyone's time.

Thanks